# discord.py embed youtube video without just pasting link

Tags: python, youtube, embed, discord.py

I am playing around with a discord.py bot, I have pretty much everything working that I need (at this time), but I can't for the life of me figure out how to embed a YouTube video using Embed().

I don't really have any code to post per-say, as none of it has worked correctly.

Note: I've tried searching everywhere (here + web), I see plenty of info on embedding images which works great.

I do see detail in the discord API for embedding video, as well as the API Documentation for discord.py; but no clear example of how to pull it off.

I am using commands (the module I am working on as a cog)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Environment:

- Discord.py Version: 0.16.11
- Python: 3.5.2
- Platform: OS X
- VirtualEnv: Yes

Answer (score 4):

What you are asking for is unfortunately impossible, since Discord API does not allow you to set custom videos in embeds.

Answer (score 1):

Only form of media you can embed is images and gifs. It’s not possible to embed a video

Answer (score 1):

I dug into this problem a bit and inspected what's going on behind the scenes but ultimately the reason seems to be that discord internally generates a proxy_url to prevent IP grabbing and the embeded video that you see in the channel comes from the proxy_url.

If you inspect the embed that discord generates when you paste a link, it is not a rich embed, but a video embed. You can actually create this video embed yourself but likely due to security reasons you cannot send it without it getting mangled.

Inspected object:

```
{'type': 'video',
 'url': 'https://example.com/video.mp4',
 'video': {'height': 480,
           'proxy_url': 'https://images-ext-1.discordapp.net/external/Tr36h2z0bxXh1JF-DYH6igRBj9SClhe_b1sxIF8CvgA/https://example.com/video.mp4',
           'url': 'https://example.com/video.mp4',
           'width': 480}}
```

How to create a custom video embed:

```
TestVideoEmbed = {}
TestVideoEmbed['type'] = 'video'
TestVideoEmbed['url'] = 'https://example.com/video.mp4'
VideoDict = {}
VideoDict['height'] = 480
VideoDict['proxy_url'] = 'https://images-ext-1.discordapp.net/external/Tr36h2z0bxXh1JF-DYH6igRBj9SClhe_b1sxIF8CvgA/https://example.com/video.mp4'
VideoDict['url'] = 'https://example.com/video.mp4'
VideoDict['width'] = 480
TestVideoEmbed['video'] = VideoDict
CreatedEmbed = discord.embeds.Embed.from_dict(TestVideoEmbed)
```

Despite the fact that you can create the video embed yourself, if you send it, somewhere along the line the discord api will turn it into a rich embed which lacks the proper fields and turns into this:

```
{'type': 'rich',
 'url': 'https://example.com/video.mp4'}
```

Ultimately, the 2 limiting factors are that we would need to be able to create the proxy_url through the api and have the final video embed be sent to the client software as a video embed without being converted.

Comment: Excellent write up. Have been searching for a while trying to see if it was possible to duplicate what Discord does when you pots a link. This settles it for me.