# Getting the url of a video of a new post using PRAW and send it to a discord server (praw, discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py, bots, reddit, praw

I'm trying to make a command in my discord.py bot that send the image or the video attacched to a post in reddit.
But, when a post is with an Image, all works fine...  when the post contains a video, that's the results:

[image]

for now I have this:

```
@client.command()
async def meme(ctx):
    subreddits = ['memesITA','yesyesyesyesno','nonononoyes','technicallythetruth','WatchPeopleDieInside','Wellthatsucks','hmmm']
    probs = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    choice = random.choice(subreddits)
    choice_num = random.choice(probs)
    count = 0
    new_messages = choice.new(limit=10)

    for post in new_messages:
        if count == choice_num:
            img_url = post.url
            title = post.title

            em = discord.Embed(title=title)
            em.set_image(url=img_url)

            await ctx.send(embed=em)

            break

        count = count + 1
```

There is no traceback because I don't receive any error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discord's API doesn't let you use custom videos in embeds, as seen in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46306032/discord-py-embed-youtube-video-without-just-pasting-link). Just look at the function's name, it's `set_image`. If you want to place a video there, maybe converting it to gif will work.

Comment: Ok thaks... I'll try to convert it into a gif

Comment: @Ghostino, found something that might help: https://gist.github.com/michaelosthege/cd3e0c3c556b70a79deba6855deb2cc8

Answer (score 0):

As an ugly workaround you can just have it paste the link on its own below the embed. This way the discord backend will properly generate a [proxy_url](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68928700/11251604) and the video will be playable from the message.

```
if hasattr(submission, 'media') and submission.media and 'reddit_video' in submission.media:
            url = safe_get(submission.media, 'reddit_video', 'fallback_url')
            await channel.send(embed=meme)
            new_msg = await channel.send(content=url)
        else:
            meme.set_image(url=submission.url)
            new_msg = await channel.send(content=None, embed=meme)
```